# Meaning of 一丁前にご指摘失礼しました

Tags: meaning, expressions

A young employee points out an error made by the boss in a blog post, the following ensues:

> boss: なるほど、あとで直しとくわ
>   employee: ありがとうございます。**一丁前にご指摘失礼しましたー**。

**QUESTION:** What does 一丁前 refer to in this dialog?

According to my dictionary, 一丁前 means "becoming an adult or full-fledged member of society".
Does the employee points out that himself has only recently become an adult, and thus is not in a position to point out errors? Or does he points out that he is not in a position to point out errors because the boss is a older than himself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [一丁前]{いっちょ(う)まえ}にご指摘失礼しました。

I think it's like "Excuse me for pointing out (your error) like / as if I am a full-fledged member/worker (of the company/society)."　≒「[一人前]{いちにんまえ}に/偉そうに指摘して、失礼しました。」

Comment: The comparison with 偉そうに made me understand the meaning of the sentence, thanks a lot!

Comment: うまく説明できなくてすいません・・・